# Clear cell value if cell in adjacent column is blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets I have two data columns, S and T.

What formula would clear the value in T if the value in S is not `RUN`?

## Sample Data

### Before

|  | S | T |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Trigger** | **Msg Status** |
| **2** |  |  |
| **3** | RUN | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 |
| **4** |  | `24/09/2023 14:44:35` |
| **5** |  |  |
| **6** |  | `24/09/2023 14:44:35` |
| **7** |  |  |
| **8** | RUN | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 |

- The values in `T4` and `T6` (highlighted above) do not have `RUN` in their adjacent column S (`S4` and `S5`).

### After (Result)

|  | S | T |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Trigger** | **Msg Status** |
| **2** |  |  |
| **3** | RUN | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 |
| **4** |  |  |
| **5** |  |  |
| **6** |  |  |
| **7** |  |  |
| **8** | RUN | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 |

- The values were cleared from `T4` and `T6`.

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SXL8Jj_nnVbEJaDzkp_eerM4IQYKg927mvkVIGze8ss/edit?usp=sharing)

<sub>**Screenshot: Example Spreadsheet**</sub>
[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

Comment: This question is a copy of [Clear Cell if S Cloumn cell value is Blank then T column cell Clear](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/236284933). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 0):

### A Jedi’s strength flows from the documentation

> *Delete data from cells it may not; only return empty or filled values, Google Sheets can.* <sup>1</sup>
>
> *This is the way* <sup>2</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup><sup><sup>1</sup> Yoda      <sup>2</sup> Din Djarin</sup></sup>

To paraphrase these great thinkers, Google Sheets functions cannot clear data from cells. They can only return values. These values can also be empty.

The "Google Sheets way" uses a formula in a separate column, such as `U1`, that returns a subset of the  values found in column T.

## Two Approaches

1. **Specific Value Formula**
   This formula looks for a specific value such as `RUN`
2. **Any Value Formula**
   This formula looks for any  value that contains at least one character.

### 1. Specific Value Formula in `U1`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  { "Your_Heading_Here";
    IF(S2:S="RUN", 
       T2:T, IFNA(#N/A)) })
```

- Returns values from `T2:T` where `S2:S="RUN"`
- Otherwise, returns a blank value

|  | S | T | U |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Trigger** | **Msg Status** | **Your_Heading_Here** |
| **2** | RUN | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 |
| **3** |  | 24/09/2023 14:44:35 |  |

### 2. Any Value Formula in `U1`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  { "Your_Heading_Here";
    IF(LEN(S2:S), 
       T2:T, IFNA(#N/A)) })
```

- Returns values from `T2:T` where `LEN(S2:S)>0`
- Otherwise, returns a blank value